# How to avoid duplication of log message when I want to change log format?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I want to change log format which will be written to  console.
I'm using spring boot, so I'm including base.xml in logback.xml.

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
```

But I realised that if I use the code above and use appender="CONSOLE" to specify log format, my log message will be duplicate.

I know that if I comment the line above out, I can stop duplication, but I must specify all the settings which has been settle in the base.xml in that case.

Could someone give me advice how should I specify log format as I use base.xml?

Here is my logbook.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="jdbc" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="INFO" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %level %logger{0} -
                %msg \(%file:%line\)%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>c:/tmp/app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.tar.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="FILE" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you. Your question it self solved my problem.

Comment: I’m happy to hear that:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now You cant do that as a configuration. Please check the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788). The feature has been requested but not yet implemented.

Comment: This has been implemented in Spring Boot 1.3